# MVC Table sorting

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, html-table, tablesorter

I'm currently playing around with the [Tablesorter](http://tablesorter.com/docs/) jQuery plugin in one of the sites I'm working on. It seems to be fairly straight forward, but for some reason the headers don't sort. Clicking on them doesn't even produce any visible response (the cursor doesn't change). I suspect this may have something to do with the fact that the table is dynamic in that it is populated by data pulled from a database table (edit: confirmed that this is not the issue by testing using static, manually entered data). The other possibility is that my jQuery code is in the wrong location or there's a problem with my reference.

Any ideas?

The project is done in MVC, by the way.

View Page Source result:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head id="Head1"><title>



    Execution History     



</title><link href="../Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script>



    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {

            $("table").tablesorter({

                headers: {

                    8: {

                        sorter: false

                    },



                    9: {

                        sorter: false

                    }

                }

            });

        });

    </script>


</head>



<body>

    <div class="page">             

        <div id="main">



    <h2>Execution History</h2>



    <table id="myTable" class="tablesorter">

        <thead>

            <tr>

                <th>Run ID</th>

                <th>Date Ran</th>

                <th>Ran By</th>

                <th>Run Time</th>

                <th>Result</th>


            </tr> 

        </thead>



        <tbody>



                <tr>

                    <td>1</td>

                    <td>7/25/2011 11:25:01 AM</td>

                    <td>Laura</td>

                    <td>145.49849999696</td>

                    <td>PASS</td>

                </tr>



                <tr>

                    <td>2</td>

                    <td>8/3/2011 6:23:01 PM</td>

                    <td>Laura</td>

                    <td>140.616000004113</td>

                    <td>PASS</td>

                </tr>



                <tr>

                    <td>3</td>

                    <td>8/3/2011 6:26:00 PM</td>

                    <td>Laura</td>

                    <td>141.592500001192</td>

                    <td>PASS</td>

                </tr>


                <tr>

                    <td>4</td>

                    <td>8/4/2011 8:04:00 PM</td>

                    <td>Kevin</td>

                    <td>260.725500002503</td>

                    <td>FAIL</td>

                </tr>


                <tr>

                    <td>5</td>

                    <td>10/5/2011 4:05:50 PM</td>

                    <td>Kevin</td>

                    <td>2749796.658</td>

                    <td>PASS</td>

                </tr>



                <tr>

                    <td>6</td>

                    <td>10/5/2011 5:31:18 PM</td>

                    <td>Kevin</td>

                    <td>2777489.2215</td>

                    <td>PASS</td>

                </tr>



        </tbody>

    </table> 





                <div id="footer"></div>

        </div>

    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I've had a lot of success with this jQuery DataTables plugin: http://datatables.net/. If you don't get anywhere with the current plugin you're using, give this one a try.

Comment: is the table sorter plugin getting initialized? Ie: are the column headers getting the table sorter classes to show they are sortable?

Comment: well, with <table class="tablesorter">, the table should be initializing the plugin. The script then hunts for <thead> and <th>, so logically there shouldn't be any issue with detecting the column headers.

Comment: It can't possibly be something extremely drastic; DataTables isn't working either, but judging from the feedback for both it and the Tablesorter plugin, the issue lies in where I'm placing my jQuery function call rather than the actual plugin's code. I'm a beginner at integrating javascript with MVC, but a quick "view page source" does show the $(document).ready(function()) {} in the <head> tag along with the reference to the sort script... I don't see where the problem could possibly lie then.

Comment: The ASP.NET code is not necessary; post the `html the browser sees` and provide a working demonstration. `:)`

Comment: I figured as much. I've edited the code to show what View Page Source returns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution. It was indeed a file reference problem. The code works fine on localhost, but I do most of my testing on IIS since this is a deployed site. Thus, a mapping is required for IIS to actually find the referenced jquery scripts. Url.Content does exactly this.

`<script src="<%=Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>`